# variable type of a class member

Tags: c++

I have an example of a structure which contains the length of 2 parameters of a class TEST

```
struct Structure 
{
 int length1;
 int length2;
}
```

The class Test will take the structure in its constructor and this is an example of the body of the class Test

```
class Test
{
public:
   Test(Structure str);
private:
   std::bitset<*> var1; // by * I mean that the type is not known at this stage
   std::bitset<*> var2;
}
```

The length of the member var1 is variable from one object to another and it should be determined from the structure str ( the element length1 will be the the length of var1 and the same for var2)

what is the better way to this kind of stuff ?

Comment: The size of a `bitset` needs to be known at compile time, so I don't think you can do this.

Answer (score 3):

Template parameters need to be known at compile-time. Unless you can somehow make the constructor constexpr and pass it a constant Structure, which may not work, you'll need a dynamic version of the `bitset` type. For this case you can use `vector<bool>`. It has a special template specialization for the type `bool` to compress the storage, so there's 8 bits stored in a byte, like a bitset.

Note that however `vector<bool>` does not act exactly like other `vector`s. For one, its `operator[]` does not return a `bool` reference, but instead a proxy type that acts like a `bool` reference in some ways. I would suggest using the reference page for the `vector<bool>` specialization specifically: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool .

Comment: Please, please don't recommend `vector<bool>`.

Comment: @cigien `vector<bool>` has serious quirks, but for most things it is just fine.

Comment: @idclev463035818 Fair enough. I tend to err on the side of caution with this one :) I generally recommend not using it, *unless* one is aware of the quirks.

Comment: @cigien thats a formulation I can agree with ;)

Comment: In my case for a future use I need that the sizeof(var1) == 4 when it will be filled with 4 bits, if I will use std::vector<bool> the sizeof will be 24

Comment: @Makkaouu why do you need that? Please include such information in the question.

Comment: @Makkaouu sizeof measures bytes. If there's 4 bits in a bitset then it will have a size of 1. As idclev463035818 said, if you have additional constraints, please include them in the question.